# Haskell extracting list from list of lists

Tags: haskell, module

Got this:

```
group167 :: (Eq a, Ord a) => [a] -> [[a]]
group167 = DL.group . DL.sort
```

Where DL is import qualified Data.List as DL. Obviously this returns a list of lists, but how to go one level up and make it just a flat list (one tier)? Just me being curious. No direct necessity to know, just want to understand. Have the feeling slowly but surely start to see the logic in Haskell.

Comment: By using `concat`, but I don't see why you use `group` then, since by using `sort`, you already will place equal elements near each other. Note that since `Ord` implies `Eq`, you can drop the redundant `Eq a` type constraint.

Comment: Or if you want only one element, by using `map head`

Comment: Still learning here, Willem :) I will get there, definitely with the help of your (valid!) comments...

Comment: If you just want to practice and do some things yourself, put a function like the following as the first in you composition. `ff . DL.group . DL sort`. The `ff` function will flatten the list. `ff [] = []; ff (x:xs) =  x ++ ff xs`

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want similar elements grouped together, don't call `group`.

```
don'tGroup167 :: Ord a => [a] -> [a]
don'tGroup167 = DL.sort
```

An aside: the `Eq a` constraint is unnecessary. `Ord a` implies `Eq a`.

Answer (score 1):

Try `concat` which is available via `Prelude`, `Data.List`, or `Data.Foldable`. How concrete this `concat` function is will depend on the package and your `ghc` version (i.e. whether it operates on `[[a]]` or `Foldable t => t [a]`)

Also look at `Control.Monad.join` which is a stronger abstraction of the *"flatten"* concept.